# Using the awk command in linux terminal to ignore repeats?

Tags: linux, bash, search, awk, duplicates

So I am working on a program that needs to scan a file with a format that causes trouble when I use the awk function.

Basically, the trouble I am having is that there are repeats that I don't want to have. For example, file looks like this:

```
abcd
abcde
```

I do a line by line search for the string "abcd", and I only want it to give me the first line, not both. Is there anything I can add to the awk function so that it searches for just the thing I'm looking for and nothing more?

I apologize if this question is dumb, but I really couldn't figure out a way to search for the problem I'm having online, and from what I've read about awk, I couldn't find a way to fix my problem.

I also cannot edit the file at all, unfortunately.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you do in your awk script when you find that line? Are you looking for many different "first lines" or just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an another way,

```
awk '/(^| )abcd( |$)/' file
```

It prints the line which contains the string `abcd` preceded by a space or a starting pattern and followed by a space or an end pattern.

**Explanation:**

- `(^| )` Matches the start of a line **OR** a space.
- `abcd` Matches the Literal `abcd`.
- `( |$)` Matches a space or a line end.
- `|` called a logical OR operator.

If a line matches the above mentioned pattern then it will be printed. You don't need to specify `'{print}'`. AWK would do it automatically.

Comment: this one worked perfectly! The other answer, for whatever reason, did not work in the context of the rest of my program. (The program is a bit more complicated than the way I wrote it above.) Anyways, this worked great, so thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: Also, do you think you could briefly explain what you're doing with the added inputs? I'd like to understand the process behind why this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
awk '/^abcd$/' file
```

or you can do

```
awk '$0=="abcd"' file
```

or if its the second field that needs to be only `abcd` not `abcde`

```
awk '$2=="abcd"' file
```

All this will only match `abcd` and not `abcde`